# Is it possible use passport.js without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, passport.js

I work in a single page app with Backbone.js, Require.js, Query in the frontend.
In the backend I use Node.js, Express.js, and I tried implementing passport.js for the user auth module but I need to not refresh the page.
Is it possible with passport.js? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in fact you should be directly hitting these express APIs from your backbone app, and within the backbone app controlling the page state.  So if you get an Unauthorized (401) response, you can change the page in your backbone app without refreshing the page (which I assume you mean redirect to a new page?)

Comment: Yes, but only for local strategy.